# Can I checkout github wikis like a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to modify and view github wikis with local editor like Emacs, and Google Code wikis can be checked out just like code. Is there any way to checkout github wikis? Or is there any other git repository provider offers such feature?

Comment: The answer is no longer correct, could you choose the correct one now?

Comment: I think this is related to programming (ableit tangentially) since I like to support my programming projects on github with wikis.  Both need flexible SCM so it makes sense.  The way to do this is just to go to the github page and click the "Clone URL" button.  The wiki address is the same as the github site with ".wiki.git" appended.  Use the standard git clone command to get a local copy for editing.

Comment: "closed as off-topic". *rolls eyes*

Answer (score 141, accepted):

[You can now!](http://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis)

```
git clone https://github.com/user/project.wiki.git
```

or if you use ssh

```
git clone git@github.com:username/project.wiki.git
```

Comment: That's great. Replacing .git suffix in your repo with .wiki, you will clone your wiki pages.

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles, Here is the actual clone syntax. **git clone git@github.com:myusername/reponame.wiki.git**

Comment: Make sure to create at least one page before cloning

Comment: And as a bonus, you can branch your wiki. The only caveat is that the wiki always only shows `master`; you can't browse different wiki branches on github.com.

Comment: @Kelvin `actual` both work. Your version requires a key registered by the system in order to work. The original answer works just fine; you just have to authenticate each time.

Comment: @Kelvin Not being a troll, calm down.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check out the wiki but you can set up a website that you can checkout and edit that gets regenerated on a push.

They call it [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/).  Admittedly, not the same as a wiki though.

Comment: Now you can - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080848/how-do-i-clone-a-github-wiki