# Clean Way to Download `.md` File From Github's Wiki Page

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Github's Wiki page shows contents with markdown-emulated page (e.g. https://github.com/github/gollum/wiki ), not the plain text of the `.md` file.

Where does Github provide us with the source of the `.md` file on its Wiki page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple clone the wiki of that project:

```
 git clone https://github.com/github/gollum.wiki.git
```

You will get `.md` files there.

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\gollum.wiki>dir

29/01/2014  07:44    <REP>          .
29/01/2014  07:44    <REP>          ..
29/01/2014  07:44                 0 .md
29/01/2014  07:44                 2 hello.md
29/01/2014  07:44            11 649 Home.md
```

See "[Can I checkout github wikis like a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484073/6309)".